# $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$ and uniform distribution

Tags: probability

I don't understand why, for a triangle defined on $(0,0)$,$(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ and a joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}$, I obtain:

- $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)=f_{XY}(x,y)\cdot($area of triangle $(0,0)$,$(2,0)$ and $(1,1))=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{2}$
- $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)=\int_{0}^{2}[\int_{0}^{2-x}f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname{dy}]\operatorname{dx}=1$

Where am I wrong if we have $0<y<x<2$?

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where am I wrong if we have 0<y<x<2?

As I told you, in any case a drawing can help

[image]

Your purpose is to integrate the joint denisty on the purple triangle. In this case the best integration order is "Y-simple"

$$\mathbb{P}[X>Y]=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{y}^{2-y}dx=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You need $y$ to be less than $x$ and less than $2-x$, or put differently $y< \min(x,2-x)$. So the correct integral is
\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(X>Y) &= \int_0^2 \int_0^{\min(x,2-x)} f(x,y) \:dy  \: dx \\ 
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x,y) \: dy \: dx + \int_1^2 \int_0^{2-x} f(x,y)\: dy \:dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{x}{2} \:dx + \int_1^2 \frac{2-x}{2} \:dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, but in reviewing my notes I have a doubt. Assuming that $X,Y\sim U(0,1)$ on a triangle of vertices $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)$ and joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)=2$, in calculating the marginal PDF of $X$ we have $f_{X}(x)=2(1-x)$ that is obtained fixing both $y<x\Rightarrow 0<y<1-x$ and $y>x\Rightarrow x<y<1$. But for your reasoning, if $y<x$, we should have $\int_{0}^{\operatorname{min}(x,1-x)}f_{XY}(x,y)$ and not only $\int_{0}^{1-x}f_{XY}(x,y)$. Why in this case do we use the operator $\operatorname{min}$?

Comment: In the above example there are two bounds for the variable $y$. The bound $2-x$ comes from the fact that $x+y \leq 2$ for $x,y$ in the triangle $(0,2),(0,0),(2,0)$ and the bound $x$ comes from the fact that the $Y<X$ on the event $\{Y< X\}$ (obviously), which is the event that we want to compute the probability off. In your new example, there are no reasons why $y$ should be less than $x$ on the triangle $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, that's what I thought, but this calls into question a lot of what I thought I understood about probabilities. This is the first exercise in which we must consider (at least explicitly) the two events. Example: $f_{XY}(x,y)=x+y$ if $0<x<1,0<y<1$. To find $\mathbb{P}(X+Y<1)$ I fixed a value of $x$ in $[0,1]$ and I varied $y$ in $[0,1-x]$, so $\int_{0}^{1}[\int_{0}^{1-x}f_{XY}(x,y)dy]dx=\frac{1}{3}$. And in this case I used the same system: I fixed a value of $x$ in $[0,2]$ and I varied $y$ in $[0,2-x]$.

Comment: It depends on what the probability you are calculating is. If you want to calculate the probability that $X+Y<2$, then for a fixed value of $x$ in $[0,2]$ we have that $y$ can vary in $[0,2-x]$, and you get that 
$$\mathbb{P}(X+Y < 2) = \int_0^2 \int_0^{2-x} f_{X , Y}(x,y) \:dy \: dx = 1,$$
but this computation is rather trivial, since $x+y < 2$ for all $(x,y)$ in the triangle and besides that, the actual event of interest was $\{Y<X\}$, and to compute that probability you need both $y<x$ and $x+y < 2$ to be satisfied.