# Doubt on the calculation of probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So far I always thought that, when it comes to compute a probability, it is necessary fixing a value of a variable ($X$ or $Y$) in its interval of definition and leaving free to vary the value of the other variable in the interval that is obtained from the union between its interval of definition and the event that we want to compute the probability off. Example:

*Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with density $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{6}{7}(x^2+\frac{xy}{2})$ if $0<x<1,0<y<2$. Find $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$.*

If $X$ is the independent variable in $[0,1]$, $Y$ is the dependent variable defined in $0<y<x<1<2\Rightarrow[0,x]$. Thus $\mathbb{P}(Y<X)=\int_{0}^{1}[\int_{0}^{x}f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname{dy}]\operatorname{dx}=\frac{15}{56}$.

Well, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806240/mathbbpxy-and-uniform-distribution/3806264?noredirect=1#comment7847353_3806264) exercise undermined my certainties. Although in fact the value of a variable ($X$) remains fixed to its interval of definition ($[0,2]$) and the interval of the other variable ($Y$) continues to be determined like union between its interval of definition and the event that we want to compute the probability ($[0,2-x]$), the event ${Y<X}$ is considered like a "third" bound, no more incorporated in the interval of $Y$. In the above example the event $Y<X$ is incorporated in $0<y<x<1$ from which we obtain the interval $[0,x]$; in [this](http://obtained%20from%20the%20union%20between%20its%20interval%20of%20definition%20and%20the%20event%20that%20we%20want%20to%20compute%20the%20probability) case, instead, the same event is both incorporated in $0<y<x<2\Rightarrow 0<y<2-x$ and considered like a third bound, from which we obtain $\mathbb{P}(Y<X)=\int_{0}^{2}[\int_{0}^{\operatorname{min}(x,2-x)}f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname{dy}]\operatorname{dx}$.

So, trivially, my question is: why? Is it correct my way of thinking or not?

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: I don't understand your first paragraph. Doesn't it... depend on the event?

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be solved changing the order of integration.

In this specific example the integrals are

$$\mathbb{P}[X>Y]=\int_{0}^{1}[\int_{0}^{x}f_{XY}(x,y)dy]dx=\int_{0}^{1}[\int_{y}^{1}f_{XY}(x,y)dx]dy$$

to understand the right integration  extremes a drawing is very useful, as I showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806240/mathbbpxy-and-uniform-distribution) replying to your question of yesterday